# How to have a small text data (what is available in the client browser) in every request processing at server side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

(It is ASP MVC 5, but I think the question and answer maybe not ASP MVC specific) If someone advice a solution, I can implement it in ASP MVC (hopefully), so I do not expect actual server side code)

Note: I mean *every* request processing at server side. Those request can come from 3rd party libs, can Ajax or not, or the end user simply typed an url to the browser.

Q:

For some reasons I would like to have a small string data (browser's Olson/IANA timezone name) available in every request in server side. I know how to get this in javascript. What I have no idea how this will be available in every request processing at server side. For performance reasons I suppose data (timezone) will not change within a session. Performance is an issue so the last thing I want frequent extra roundtrips. (Now please excuse my beginner thoughts, one or more can be completely wrong.)

Idea A)
Maybe I can store it in a cookie with javascript. I am not sure will it available at server side in every request?

Idea B) 
In every request processing at server side I check if the server's session has this value set. If not... (I can not continue, then what? I can not call back to the client, and the data is mandatory in this very request too)

Idea C) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A cookie would definitely be the right way to go as it will be available to the server in all subsequent requests defined by the lifetime you give to the cookie.  You may want to define some generic handler on the server for the cookie data such as an http module or mvc filter.

Comment: @Jason: Thx I've tried it, and worked. In case you post it as answer I am going to accept it.